# Multiple Select statements in one Query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to run multiple select statements in one query in SQLite?

Such as:

```
SELECT ( 
           SELECT ChestGemEffects.Value,
                  Effect.Name
             FROM ChestGemEffects
                  INNER JOIN Effect
                          ON ChestGemEffects.EffectId = Effect.Id
                  INNER JOIN Gems
                          ON ChestGemEffects.GemId = Gems.Id
            WHERE ( Gems.[Key] = 'SG1' )  
       ) 
       AS ChestEffects,
       ( 
           SELECT WeaponGemEffects.Value,
                  Effect.Name
             FROM WeaponGemEffects
                  INNER JOIN Effect
                          ON WeaponGemEffects.EffectId = Effect.Id
                  INNER JOIN Gems
                          ON WeaponGemEffects.GemId = Gems.Id
            WHERE ( Gems.[Key] = 'SG1' )  
       ) 
       AS WeaponEffects,
       ( 
           SELECT OthersGemEffects.Value,
                  Effect.Name
             FROM OthersGemEffects
                  INNER JOIN Effect
                          ON OthersGemEffects.EffectId = Effect.Id
                  INNER JOIN Gems
                          ON OthersGemEffects.GemId = Gems.Id
            WHERE ( Gems.[Key] = 'SG1' )  
       ) 
       AS OthersEffects;
```

It gives me the error:

'Error while executing query: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression'

Is there something wrong with my expression or is this just not supported in SQLite?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the result of a subquery as a source table for further querying must be done in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...), (SELECT ...)
```

However, this would be a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), which is not what you want.

To just append multiple tables (with the same number of columns), use [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT ChestGemEffects.Value,
       Effect.Name
  FROM ...
  ...
UNION ALL
SELECT WeaponGemEffects.Value,
       Effect.Name
  FROM ...
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I decided to send a different query for each select.