# sqlite - two selects on the same database

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have some problems with my application (you can check my other threads), and I'm not sure why my database is locked.

Maybe I can not call two selects, because my database open uses the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` option?

is it possible to call TWO `SELECT` on the same database (same thread, consecutive)

What I do?

```
int rcc = sqlite3_open_v2(str_sessions_file.c_str(), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL );
```

then

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer, strlen(buffer), &stmt, 0) != SQLITE_OK)
```

then

```
while( sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW )
```

and inside this `while` I call another `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to make `select` with new `stmt` and then `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: maybe I can not call two `selects` because my database open as READWRITE?

Comment: Your P.S. should be your **primary question**, besides your comment I've been adding there!

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253535/multiple-select-statements-in-one-query-in-sqlite

Comment: thank you @πάνταῥεῖ. and  thanks for suggestion, but i'm not able to use two selects in the same request, because some data not ready on the program. :(